# Linux 3.13.3 headers

Tags: linux-kernel

My problem seems rather simple, but I've searched through dozens of pages and still haven't found a sufficient solution.

I use Debian 32-bit with linux 3.13.3 kernel on my VM but there are no linux-headers installed. As you can easily presume I need them badly to test some new module implementation.

First I've tried this:

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/7.5/chapter06/linux-headers.html

but sadly the problem still exists. (i.e. during compilation /lib/modules/linux-3.13.3/build does not exist)

Alternative method is here:

http://www.yourownlinux.com/2014/02/install-upgrade-to-linux-kernel-3-13-3-in-linux.html

and it works great, but the problem is I don't want to change kernel version to linux-3.13.3-031303-generic_3.13.3-031303 I need exactly the 3.13.3 version

Does anyone know where can I find pure 3.13.3 headers? 
Additionally, if it's not a big problem, I'd be grateful for the best method to install them.

Edit: I've forgotten to mention the simplest way: obviously, apt-get does not contain packages with linux-headers-3.13.3.

Comment: How about these instructions? http://kometchtech.blog45.fc2.com/blog-entry-1358.html Change the samples to 3.13.3.

Comment: Done this too, but as you can see here http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.13.3-trusty/, these are headers for 3.13.3-031303-generic_3.13.3-031303. Is it possible that there are no headers dedicated for 3.13.3[fullstop] version of kernel?